# How to override default Polymer CSS

Tags: css, polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

Right now `core-toolbar` has an `indent` class that indents the title to the right by `60px`, while material design dictates that the margin should actually be `80px` (as a matter of fact the number `60` never shows throughout the documentation).

So I could easily go and edit it in `bower_components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.css` but the problem is that, once I move the project somewhere else, I'd have to make the same edit once I've done my bower installs etc..

Mind you that if I was to extend `core-toolbar` say, I'd have a problem with `core-header-panel` etc.. because it would be looking for either `<core-toolbar>` or something with the class `"core-header"` which is a bit of an annoyance, but it's something I can live with.

What's the best way to do something like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach might be to globally override core-toolbar's style using something like http://jsbin.com/soveyo/12/edit Note that I've only got native shadow dom support there.

Or you could do that in a particular instance if you'd prefer & remove the html /deep/ bit.

Or you might add your own class to the element you're giving as content to the toolbar & give it the indentation you want.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try creating your own toolbar element 
A noscript polymer-element, with just you css style and a core-toolbar in it.
Something like :

```
<polymer-element name="my-toolbar" noscript>
<template>
  <style>
    core-toolbar { /* xxxx */ }
  </style>
  <core-toolbar><content></content></core-toolbar>
</template>
</polymer-element>
```

Or even better, you can extend the core-toolbar to keep all the attributes handling from the core-toolbar

Comment: Problem with this approach is that it won't work with elements leveraging core-toolbar, such as core-header-panel.